# datasheet view create item sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, view, sharepoint-2010, content-type, sharepoint-list

I am creating sub sites using a site template (Site template was created using "Save site as template" method).
I have a task list within this template with two content types. I have made one content type as default. The other one is used for creating some default tasks which comes along with the site template.
I want the users to create tasks only through the first content type by default. This works fine in the standard view, but when I switch to the datasheet view and create a new task from here, it takes the second content type for creating the task and not the default content type.
I searched a lot for the answer to this, but in vain.
A kind help here is deeply appreciated.

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: Don't know for sure but... (cant test it atm) I think the datasheet view is based on a view. Not on a content type. Maybe create a custom view based on the default content type columns? Don't know if it works...

Comment: Thanks for your comment friend. But here the issue is what if the user switches from standard view to the datasheet view; and here creates a new item? How to handle this?